# How to manage multiple unique instances of an I/O device

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a I/O serial device (a class, calling it here `SerialPort`) that other parts of my program will read/write to. `SerialPort` handles the connection to the port (pyserial), threading of the I/O, and is implemented as a pub/sub design, other classes in my program get called back if there is a new message, or can write new messages. The device has >100 supported messages and responses, hence the pub/sub design (not the center of this question but just wanted to clarify choice).

Now I need to add 2 (or more) of the same device. What I would like to do is have any observer call something like:

```
# The name of the devices and corresponding serial ports are known at run time. So in the program there will be N known devices.

# Where SerialPort("UniqueName1") is connected to port /dev/ttyUSB0
some_observer = Observer(SerialPort("UniqueName1"))
# Where SerialPort("UniqueName2") is connected to port /dev/ttyUSB2
other_observer = Observer(SerialPort("UniqueName2"))
# Here some_observer and random_observer both get the same instance of SerialPort("UniqueName1")
random_observer = Observer(SerialPort("UniqueName1"))
```

Where in Observer() an instance (or an interface) of SerialPort is kept, so Observer can write, and register callbacks to SerialPort. The part I am stuck on is how to handle that every call to SerialPort("UniqueName1") should just return the already connected SerialPort object (assuming its been connected/initialized earlier). Observer should just be able to say "I want to talk to a device with UniqueName1 (or 2)"

In this fashion I could then have an observer of both SerialPort objects by keeping two (or more) SerialPort references in Observer. I dont need to do this, but this design does not restrict me if I need to in the future.

Any advice on how to do this in python (2.7)? I am new to python, googling as I go. I just need help on where I should put the python/pseudo code below. I tried to put this in the class Serialport but the `SerialPort.__init__(name)` did not let me return an already created SerialPort device

```
# Somewhere in the code
sp = SerialPort(name="UniqueName1")
# Now in SerialPort, where all_serial_ports = list of available SerialPorts
for serial_ports in all_serial_ports:
    if serial_ports.name == name:
        return serial_port
# Did not find serial port (need to do something)
```

Comment: Do you really want this to be handled by the constructor of the `SerialPort` class, instead of a call to some instance of a `SerialPorts` or `SerialPortManager` class—or just a lookup in a public dict?

Comment: @abarnert Im not sure, not sure what makes the most sense. If it was handled by a SerialPortManager, would it be something like SerialPortManager.get_serial_port("UniqueName1")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it *is* possible to intercept the `SerialPort` constructor so that `SerialPort("UniqueName1")` returns the existing value (if any) instead of creating a new one,<sup>1</sup> that's usually not what you want to do.

The simplest solution is to just store a dict of serial ports, but this requires manually looking things up each time:

```
if "UniqueName1" not in ports:
    ports["UniqueName1"] = SerialPort("UniqueName1")
some_observer = Observer(ports["UniqueName1"])
```

So, you might want to make the dict private and wrap up the access in a function:

```
def getport(name):
    if port not in _ports:
        ports[name] = SerialPort(name)
    return ports[name]
```

And now you just call that function:

```
some_observer = Observer(getport("UniqueName1"))
```

You can just put this function in the same module as your `SerialPort` or `Observer` class.

If you might have multiple different name-to-ports mappings, you'd probably want to instead wrap this in a `SerialPortManager` class whose instances have a `self._ports` and a `getport` method, but otherwise you don't need that.

---

<sub>1. If you really do want to intercept the constructor, the way to do that is with a [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method. The default implementation just returns a new empty object of your type, and if you return that, your `__init__` method gets called. But you can return anything else you want instead. Which includes not calling the `super()` version and instead looking up a value in some private dict.</sub>

Comment: Your right, I probably should keep it simple and not make it over complicated. I will however check out the `__new__` for my own learning.

Comment: @user2840470 The one tricky thing to watch out for with `__new__` is that whether it calls `__init__` depends entirely on whether what you return passes `isinstance(obj, cls)`, not on whether you retrieved it through `super().__new__` or not. The simplest solution is usually to make `__init__` idempotent (or even a no-op) and do the initialization inside `__new__` instead. If you search for singleton libraries, you should find some examples of that.